# Cannot log in to phpMyAdmin with users account: Get root override message

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, phpmyadmin

I am trying to access phpMyAdmin but I get: `"You are logged in with the root, or reseller's password"` message, even though I am logged in using the users account (not my root account).

I have tried clearing the cache and using another browser to no affect.

Does anyone know a way round this?

Comment: Who is your host?

Answer (score 1):

Try to access phpMyAdmin not from the WHM panel, but from the cPanel using the login details of a specific user, not the login details of a root user.

In case you are not able to access phpMyAdmin from cPanel, this means that you need to get in touch with support and ask them for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cPanel and click on the phpMyAdmin icon from there.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it gives me the same error message

Comment: @MeltingDog You actually have to log into the users cPanel - not WHM at all. Then you'll be able to use phpMyAdmin.